# Mysql get rows until value equal certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a query like this:

```
SELECT u.email, st.value as score,
date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) as fecha,
IF(st.value >= 70, 'YES', 'NO') as result
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN scorm_scoes_track st ON st.userid = u.id 
LEFT JOIN scorm_scoes as ss ON ss.scorm = st.scormid
WHERE (st.element='cmi.score.raw' OR st.element='cmi.core.score.raw') 
ORDER BY u.id, st.timemodified

+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------+
| email            | score      | fecha               | result   |
+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------+
| test@test.es     | 45         | 14-03-2015 17:10:18 | NO       |
| test@test.es     | 65         | 14-03-2015 17:12:42 | NO       |
| test@test.es     | 70         | 14-03-2015 17:15:04 | YES      |
| test@test.es     | 60         | 14-03-2015 17:17:16 | NO       |
| test@test.es     | 65         | 14-03-2015 17:17:16 | NO       |
+------------------+------------+---------------------+----------+
```

User passes the test if result is greater/equal than 70. We need that only results until 70 (when test is passed) will be shown.

In this case, we need this result:

```
| test@test.es     | 45         | 14-03-2015 17:10:18 | NO       |
| test@test.es     | 65         | 14-03-2015 17:12:42 | NO       |
| test@test.es     | 70         | 14-03-2015 17:15:04 | YES      |
```

Because results after score is >= 70 have to be discarted

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Move the two st.element conditions from WHERE clause to the st's ON clause to do a LEFT JOIN. (As it is now you get an INNER JOIN...)

Comment: `WHERE (st.element='cmi.score.raw' OR st.element='cmi.core.score.raw') AND result = 'YES `

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the question...we need results before 70 is reached

Comment: Add where date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) < (select date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(st .timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) .... from table where 70 etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Add `st.value` to `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT u.email, st.value as score,
date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) as fecha,
IF(st.value >= 70, 'YES', 'NO') as result
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN scorm_scoes_track st ON st.userid = u.id 
LEFT JOIN scorm_scoes as ss ON ss.scorm = st.scormid
WHERE (st.element='cmi.score.raw' OR st.element='cmi.core.score.raw') AND st.value >= 70 
ORDER BY u.id, st.timemodified
```

Comment: Move all the st.element conditions from WHERE clause to the st's ON clause to do a LEFT JOIN. (As it is now you get an INNER JOIN...)

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the question...we need results before 70 is reached

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a **WHERE** statement ?

```
SELECT u.email, st.value as score,
date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(st.timemodified),'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' ) as fecha,
IF(st.value >= 70, 'YES', 'NO') as result
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN scorm_scoes_track st ON st.userid = u.id 
LEFT JOIN scorm_scoes as ss ON ss.scorm = st.scormid
WHERE (st.element='cmi.score.raw' OR st.element='cmi.core.score.raw')
AND st.value >= 70
ORDER BY u.id, st.timemodified
```

I just added the line *AND st.value >= 70* on your original query